# How to Import Categories with Descriptions from a CSV File?

Tags: categories, import, bulk-import

How could I import a list of new categories and category descriptions from a file of Comma Separated Values?

Comment: You hav a csv file, and you want that for your category description ?

Comment: What do you mean? The categories already exist and you want to import only descriptions? **Please**, add more details to your Question... Oh, yes, welcome to WPSE and remember to read the FAQ :)

Answer (score 4):

Very simple plugin to achieve this.

Runs only on activation, so, if there are 5 CSV files, the plugin must be activated/deactivated five times.

### File:

#### `/wp-content/plugins/create-cats-from-csv/create-cats-from-csv.php`

```
<?php
/*
    Plugin Name: Insert CSV Categories
    Version: 1.0
    Description: Reads a CSV file on plugin activation and insert the Categories/Description/Parent into WordPress as defined in the CSV
    Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/57865/12615
    Author: brasofilo 
    Author URI: http://rodbuaiz.com
*/
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'wpse_57865_activation_run');

function wpse_57865_activation_run()
{
    // THE PREG_SPLIT IS NOT ADEQUATE FOR COMPLEX STRINGS
    // Code snippet: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7502370/1287812
    $file = file_get_contents( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . 'categories.csv' );
    $data = array_map( "str_getcsv", preg_split( '/\r*\n+|\r+/', $file ) );

    if( count($data) < 1)
        return;

    // http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_category
    foreach( $data as $cat )
    {
        $cat_defaults = array(
          'cat_name' => $cat[0],
          'category_description' => $cat[1] 
        );

        wp_insert_category($cat_defaults);
    }

}
```

### File:

#### `/wp-content/plugins/create-cats-from-csv/categories.csv`

> ```
> Category Title, Category Description
> First Category, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
> Second Category, Consectetur adipisicing elit
> Third Category, Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
> ```

Comment: i think you should update this code to use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php instead of preg split - you don't have to map it - simply read line after line.

Comment: What to do if i want to create child category?

Comment: @Hasibur, [`category_parent`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_category/) on the $cat_defaults array