# Batch upload to create posts each with one image, headline, and body text

Tags: uploads, bulk-import

I've been handed 300 images, 300 headlines, and 300 paragraphs by a client. Is there a way for me to place all of this in a CSV file (or other format) and upload the whole shebang into a fresh WordPress install in one operation? I don't have php skills so I need a simple solution if there is one. Thanks.

Comment: This plugin should do the trick:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-all-import/

Comment: What a solution should that be? Plugin recommendations are off topic here, and without code it will not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something along the lines:

- Prepare a spreadsheet with all the data to be exported as CSV
- Use a plugin to import: [Importing data from spreadsheet into wordpress DB, along with custom taxonomies and their terms](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/48091/12615)
- Or custom code: [How to Import Categories with Descriptions from a CSV File?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/57865/12615)

If possible, use a development installation to do the CSV import. So you can fine tune all the posts and do a default WordPress XML export.

Beside fine-tuning, the previous step may be needed to handle the images. As far as I know, CSV import won't bring them as attachments, only as post meta (custom fields).

I can't point to any ready-made code, only to the needed function: [`media_handle_sideload`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=media_handle_sideload).

Once this is done, refer to this Q&A for the final step of Export/Import using local images: [Import media to online WordPress from local development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/87395/12615)